# replacement for window.external.invoke in browser JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, webview

I have a webview into which I have injected some HTML to display a button and then some JavaScript that is triggered by the button's `onClick` attribute.

```
    console.log("\ninvoking from PC with " + JSON.stringify(arg));
    window.external.invoke(JSON.stringify(arg));
    console.log("invoked");
```

The WebView is actually a [Rust webview](https://github.com/Boscop/web-view).

It seems that this has stopped working. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/external) says "this feature may cease to work at any time", which presumably is what has happened.

So does anyone know what I should be doing? Throw away all my code because Mozilla has decided to remove a feature from FireFox without a replacement?

Comment: WebView uses WebKit which is controlled by Google, not Mozilla. Don’t blame the messenger.

Comment: Er, yes. Sorry, Mozilla. Though I am using Fedora so it might be something else.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it by replacing the invoke line with

```
    window.webkit.messageHandlers.external.postMessage(JSON.stringify(arg));
```

as per [philwrenn's comment on the Rust crate's matching error](https://github.com/Boscop/web-view/issues/280#issuecomment-819774833)